# LESS CSS Client-Side usage on Azure

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, azure, less

We just switched our WordPress-Site on an Azure Server.

For the development of our theme we use `LESS CSS` with the Client-Side JS file.

Since we switched, it says that the less file does not exist on our server - but it does. We have a `.css` file in the same folder and Azure can find the .css file.

**This is the console output:**

> GET
>   http://wordpress.website.com/wp-content/themes/default-v3/assets/less/bootstrap.less
>   404 (Not Found)b.exports.g.doXHR @ less.js:13b.exports.g.loadFile @
>   less.js:13j @ less.js:13k @ less.js:13b.exports.n.refresh @
>   less.js:13b.exports.n.refresh @ less.js:132../add-default-options @
>   less.js:13e @ less.js:13a @ less.js:13(anonymous function) @
>   less.js:13i @ less.js:13(anonymous function) @ less.js:13 less.js:13
>
> Uncaught (in promise) Object {type: "File", message:
>   "'http://wordpress.website.com/wp-content/themes/default-v3/assets/less/bootstrap.less'
>   wasn't found (404)", href:
>   "http://wordpress.website.com/wp-content/themes/default-v3/assets/less/bootstrap.less"}

What can we do about this?

Comment: Is it possible that you have some kind of rewrite rules active that only work on css files? Have you tried renaming the css file to less to see if that affects the availability?

Comment: It looks like. When I rename the css file to less it gives me an error 404

Comment: Then I suggest you look into possible rewrite rules. If you're using Apache this involves checking every .htaccess file on te path to the file (if .htaccess is enabled). In nginx these rules should be in the site configuration file. IIS is a blank spot for me. Of course it could be something completely different but rewrite rules are the first thing that crossed my mind.

Comment: Seems like a mime type issue. Have you tried adding a mimeMap to the web.config? Here is an example http://madskristensen.net/post/prepare-webconfig-for-html5-and-css3